# Record validation to identify error records by string comparison

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to read avro records from a topic and validate it before loading it into a table.
It's a normal validation, based on below scenario :

There are two fields in the schema, VP and AH.

**Condition 1:**

```
VP and AH can't have A value at the same time, set err_val ='E' in this case.
```

**Condition 2:**

```
 VP and AH must have value A or I, set err_val = 'E' in case of any other value.
```

So, my condition is like this :

```
    // logic to identify error records
        if ((record.value().get("AH").toString().equals("A") && record.value().get("VP").toString().equals("A")) 
                || ((!"I".equals(record.value().get("AH").toString())) || (!"A".equals(record.value().get("AH").toString())))
                    || ((!"I".equals(record.value().get("VP").toString())) || (!"A".equals(record.value().get("VP").toString())))
                )
        {
        
                id              = record.value().get("ID").toString();
                id_type         = record.value().get("ID_TYPE").toString();
                ah              = record.value().get("AH").toString();
                vp              = record.value().get("VP").toString();
                effective_date  = record.value().get("EFFECTIVE_DATE").toString();
                end_date        = record.value().get("END_DATE").toString();
                err_val         = "E";
     } else {
                id              = record.value().get("ID").toString();
                id_type         = record.value().get("ID_TYPE").toString();
                ah              = record.value().get("AH").toString();
                vp              = record.value().get("VP").toString();
                effective_date  = record.value().get("EFFECTIVE_DATE").toString();
                end_date        = record.value().get("END_DATE").toString();
                err_val         = "";
         
       
        }
```

The condition 1 is handled by first line inside if statement and it's working as expected.
But, the next two lines are not working for condition 2.

Even if I am producing record like this :

```
value={"ID": "461761581", "ID_TYPE": "IN", "AH": "I", "VP": "A", "EFFECTIVE_DATE": "20200501", "END_DATE": "20991231"}
```

I am getting 'E' in the output, which is not correct.

```
461761581,IN,I,A,20200501,20991231,E
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String AH = record.value().get("AH").toString();
String VP = record.value().get("VP").toString();

Set<String> filter = Set.of("A", "I");

if (("A".equals(AH) && "A".equals(VP)) || (!filter.contains(AH) && !filter.contains(VP))) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

You can also use [String.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

```
if (("A".equals(AH) && "A".equals(VP)) || (!AH.matches("A|I") && !VP.matches("A|I"))) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```